# wrror with mongodb query on node.js named MongoServerError: cannot infer query fields to set, path 'channelId' is matched twice

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

query is here

```
ChannelSubscribers.updateOne(
      {
        $and: [
          { "channelId": userChannelId },
          { "subscriberId": dict.subscriberId },
        ],
      },
      {
        $set: {
          "subscriptionDate": dict.subscribedOn,
          "subscriberName": dict.subscriberName,
          "subscriberDescription": dict.subscriberDescription,
          "subscriberThumbnail": dict.subscriberThumbnail,
          "updatedAt": new Date().toISOString(),
        },
        $setOnInsert: { "channelId": userChannelId,"createdAt": new Date().toISOString(),"subscriberId": dict.subscriberId },
      },
      { upsert: true }
    );
```

above query works fine with studio3t but gives error in vs code when i run it with node.js

please solve the above query

Answer (score 1):

When MongoDB does an upsert, all of the values that were matched in the filter will be set in the new document.

To fix the error, remove the fields from the `$setOnInsert` document that are in the filter part of the update, as they will already be set in the new document.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5XG6RG_PIIx)

Comment: its not working then also,

Comment: Does the linked playground not do what you are looking for?